# Custom fonts heavily aliased in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-face, custom-font

I've heard Chrome 37 fixes this but at the moment, Opera and IE look much better with my custom fonts than Chrome and Firefox.

***Examples***

- First image Chunk-five is Chrome (same in Firefox)
- Second is Chunk-five in IE (same in Opera)

[image]

[image]

EDIT - here's my font declaration

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
    src: url('/Content/Fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), 
         url("/Content/Fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("/Content/Fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("/Content/Fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.svg#webfontb5K2fJwj") format("svg");

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**How can I fix this?**

EDIT - moving the svg line higher up fixed it for Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: Very interesting... did you have a question?

Comment: How do I fix it? My bad, I thought it was implied.